# Please, help with the mistakes with table

Tags: tables, errors

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Население в регионе & Оценка (вес - 2) & Реализованная инфраструктура  & Оценка (вес - 4) \\ 
    \hline 
    < 25 000 & 1 & > 76% & 1 \\ 
    \hline 
    25 000 - 45 000 & 2 & 51 - 75.99 & 2 \\ 
    \hline 
    45 000 - 90 000 & 3 & 15 - 50.99 & 3 \\ 
    \hline 
    > 90 001 & 4 & 0.01 - 14.99 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

**I tried to create a table with the help of "wizards". I see the table in my document, but i see the mistakes too (on the picture). 75 line is "25000..." **[image]

Thank you and sorry for my english and presentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For latex % is a special character, if you want to use it in your table you need to escape it with `\%`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    aaa & bbb & ccc  & ddd \\ 
    \hline 
    $< 25 000$ & 1 & $> 76\%$ & 1 \\ 
    \hline 
    25 000 - 45 000 & 2 & 51 - 75.99 & 2 \\ 
    \hline 
    45 000 - 90 000 & 3 & 15 - 50.99 & 3 \\ 
    \hline 
    $> 90 001$ & 4 & 0.01 - 14.99 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 


\end{document}
```